# EHcache in clustered environment

Tags: ehcache

We plan to use Ehcache in our application that resides in a cluster. However we do not want to use Terracotta SA, what are the other options for cache replication across all the servers in cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick answer is: No.

With Ehcache 2 you could, but it wasn't really reliable. With Ehcache 3, the clustered is done using a terracotta server. This has always been the most reliable way.

Note that the terracotta server is open source.